# Eclipse shows "Target entity "java.lang.Object" is not an Entity "

Tags: eclipse, jpa, jpa-2.0

In my JPA code i use:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntityVotes<T> extends BaseEntity {
    /**
     * The entity this vote belongs to.
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    private T entity;
```

But Eclipse can't validate: "Target entity "java.lang.Object" is not an Entity".
(no error in IntelliJ)
I tried to change the type parameter to `<T extends BaseEntity>` (BaseEntity is also a MappedSuperclass) but this only changes the error text accordingly. Is this a real problem? Or is this a bug in eclipse?

In this regard i found [a fixed bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=336133). But this didn't helped. So is there a fix or work around to get rid of this error or can i fix the code in some way?

Comment: what else do you expect Eclipse to say? it knows nothing regarding the constraints on the type T, so assumes Object and you annotated the field as ManyToOne, so must be a relation. If you put a "extends SomeEntity" as a constraint on T then you may get success

Comment: as i said "extends BaseEntity which is another MappedSuper class does not help. Is there a way to disable this specific check?

Comment: Sorry missed your extends line; with the extends I'd say a bug, without not. Some JPA implementations also have incomplete handling of generic Type variables so some require you to put the root entity type in rather than the generic. Raise a bug on Eclipse for the extends case

Comment: is there a way to disable this check?

Comment: No idea ... you refer to a bug in EclipseLink (JPA implementation) yet is this error from Eclipse itself in its JPA tools?

Comment: i filed a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=485480.
I am not sure what part of eclipse raises this. It shows like every compiler error but with type "JPA Problem"